# PyMC3: How to use pymc3.traceplot() to overlap means on traceplot

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

There is a function `pymc3.traceplot()` that plots the traceplots of the sampling process.  I see that the function takes an argument `lines` that takes a dictionary, in which you can pass the means as lines to be plotted. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any value you want not only the mean.

```py
theta_val = 0.35
pm.traceplot(trace, lines={'theta':theta_val})
```

[image]

`theta` is the name of the variable in the model and `theta_val` is the value you want to plot (overlap).

You can compute the mean from the trace by doing:

```
trace['theta'].mean()
```

or you can also do something like:

```py
lines = {var:trace[var].mean() for var in trace.varnames}
```

Comment: hey @aloctavodia, that works if you precompute the mean values for the variables. What if you want to programmatically compute the mean for each variable?

Comment: Hi! I edited my answer. Please, let me know if that is what you want.

Comment: perfect! That was what I was looking for.